# How do I use a hostname instead of IP address when making a "route" entry?

Tags: windows, routing, route

I need to make it so that two hostnames use a specific network interface. That is, so that any connection from my computer to those two hostnames go through that specified network interface. Windows 10.

Somebody told me to use the "route" command, but it wants me to enter an IP address instead of hostname.

**When I ping the hostnames in question, they return different IP addresses all the time, or gives different ones to different people. I thus cannot rely on whatever it tells me at any given time.**

How do I make it so that any request to xyz.example.com and zyx.example.com always use a given network interface on my machine?

Comment: You can't use host names in route.

Answer (score 1):

IP routing works with... IP, not DNS

Best you can do is script something that resolve the hostname to its IP and inject/refresh the IP in the route table. (that's what new generation firewalls that allow FQDN routing does)